# how to make hide/show text javascript smoother?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this script to hide and show text however, I want to make the transition smoother but I am not sure how to. Here's a demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/LnE5U/.

Please help me change it to make it smoother.

```
<a href="javascript:showOrHide();">hide/show text</a>
<div id="showOrHideDiv" style="display: none">hidden text</div>


<script language="javascript">
    function showOrHide() 
    {
        var div = document.getElementById("showOrHideDiv");
        if (div.style.display == "block") 
        {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else 
        {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout` loop with `div.style.opacity`? _jQuery's_ `animate` makes this easy. Othewise, CSS transitions.

Comment: @PaulS. where would I put this in the code then? sorry, I am not familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using *jQuery's* [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) (a shortcut for a more complicated `animate`)

```
// assuming jQuery
$(function () {                      // on document ready
    var div = $('#showOrHideDiv');   // cache <div>
    $('#action').click(function () { // on click on the `<a>`
        div.fadeToggle(1000);        // toggle div visibility over 1 second
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="action" href="#">hide/show text</a>
<div id="showOrHideDiv" style="display: none;">hidden text</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECTP/)

---

An example of a pure *JavaScript* fader. It looks complicated because I wrote it to support changing direction and duration mid-fade. I'm sure there are still improvements that could be made to it, though.

```
function generateFader(elem) {
    var t = null, goal, current = 0, inProgress = 0;
    if (!elem || elem.nodeType !== 1) throw new TypeError('Expecting input of Element');
    function visible(e) {
        var s = window.getComputedStyle(e);
        return +!(s.display === 'none' || s.opacity === '0');
    }
    function fader(duration) {
        var step, aStep, fn, thisID = ++current, vis = visible(elem);
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        if (inProgress) goal = 1 - goal; // reverse direction if there is one running
        else goal = 1 - vis;             // else decide direction
        if (goal) {                      // make sure visibility settings correct if hidden
            if (!vis) elem.style.opacity = '0';
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
        step = goal - +window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;
        step = 20 * step / duration;     // calculate how much to change by every 20ms
        if (step >= 0) {                 // prevent rounding issues
            if (step < 0.0001) step = 0.0001;
        } else if (step > -0.0001) step = -0.0001;
        aStep = Math.abs(step);          // cache
        fn = function () {
            // console.log(step, goal, thisID, current); // debug here
            var o = +window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;
            if (thisID !== current) return;
            if (Math.abs(goal - o) < aStep) {            // finished
                elem.style.opacity = goal;
                if (!goal) elem.style.display = 'none';
                inProgress = 0;
                return;
            }
            elem.style.opacity = (o + step).toFixed(5);
            t = window.setTimeout(fn, 20);
        }
        inProgress = 1; // mark started
        fn();           // start
    }
    return fader;
}
```

And using it

```
window.addEventListener( // this section matches the code above
    'load',
    function () {
        var fader = generateFader(document.getElementById('showOrHideDiv'));
        document.getElementById('action').addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
                fader(1000);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

[**DEMO of this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECTP/1/)

Comment: You should read this ( from stackoverflow tag description ) *JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, **a pure JavaScript answer is expected**.*

Comment: @Connor this answer is a follow up to the [comment above asking for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512079#comment25460679_17512079) and it is explicitly stated in the answer that it uses _jQuery_.

Answer (score 2):

> This is quite simple. I have just made a demo and i used setInterval
>
> Here's how it works

```
var fadeout = function( element ) { // 1
    element.style.opacity = 1; // 2
    window.setInterval(function() { // 3
        if(element.style.opacity > 0) { // 4
            element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity - 0.01).toFixed(2); // 5 
        } else {
            element.style.display = 'none'; // 6 
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

[JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LnE5U/3/)

> #### Steps
>
> 1. Create a function that accepts a DOM element
> 2. Set the opacity of the element to 1
> 3. Create a function that loops every 50ms
> 4. If the opacity is greater than 0 -> continue
> 5. Take away 0.01 from the opacity
> 6. if it's less than 0 the animation is complete and hide it completely

Note this is a really simple example and will need a bit of work

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this

```
    $('.showOrHideDiv').toggle(function() {
      $('showOrHideDiv').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        //fadeIn or fadeOut, slow or fast, all the stuffs you want to trigger, "a function to execute every odd time the element is clicked," says the  [jquery doc][1]
        });
    }, function() {
        //here comes "additional handlers to cycle through after clicks," says the [jquery doc][1]
    });
```

Comment: You should read this ( from stackoverflow tag description ) *JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, **a pure JavaScript answer is expected**.*

Answer (score 0):

I **used OPACITY** to make it **show/hide**. See this Example, Full code (without jQuery):

```
<a href="javascript:ShowDiv('MyMesage');"> Click here</a>

<div id="MyMesage" style="display:none; background-color:pink; margin:0 0 0 100px;width:200px;">
blablabla
</div>

<script>
function ShowDiv(name){
    //duration of transition (1000 miliseconds equals 1 second)
    var duration = 1000;
    // how many times should it should be changed in delay duration
    var AmountOfActions=100;

    var diiv= document.getElementById(name);
    diiv.style.opacity = '0';   diiv.style.display = 'block';   var counte=0;
    setInterval(function(){counte ++;
       if ( counte<AmountOfActions) { diiv.style.opacity = counte/AmountOfActions;}
    },
    duration / AmountOfActions);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed iConnor solution and works fine but it had a small issue setInterval will not stop after the element be hidden I added stop interval to make it better performance

```
var fadeout = function( element ) { // 1
    element.style.opacity = 1; // 2
    let hidden_process = window.setInterval(function() { // 3
        if(element.style.opacity > 0) { // 4
            element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity - 0.01).toFixed(2); // 5 
        } else {
            element.style.display = 'none'; // 6 
            console.log('1');
            clearInterval(hidden_process);
        }
    }, 50);
    
    
};
```